# python mongoengine aggregate lookup

Tags: python, aggregate, mongoengine

Let's say I have two collections, **dogs** and **dog_owners**.

**dog** documents have ***name*** and ***owner*** attributes, ***owner*** being an **ObjectId** referencing a **dog_owner** ***_id*** attribute.

***dog_owners*** have only a ***name*** attribute.

I want to query all dogs but replace the owner attribute which has an id to the reference owner's name.

It's the first time I'm using mongoengine in python, the query would be something like this:

```
dogs = dogs.objects().aggregate(pipeline)
```

can somebody help me with the pipeline using $lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go in python3.

Your `dog` object will have new field `dog_owner` attached. It won't replace `dog.owner`, but I think it's good enough.

```py
cursor = Dog.objects.aggregate([
    {"$lookup": {
        "from": DogOwner._get_collection_name(),
        "localField": "dog_owner_id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "dog_owner"
    }},
])
```